# How can I extract the route name (path) on express nodejs (during the call, from the req)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I have nodejs express server, containing a generic middleware. There, I would like to get the route name. For example:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  //using some npm pkg allowing me to run function after res.status was sent. This code runs at the very end of the request (after the response)
  onHeaders(res, function () {
    //console #1
    console.log(req.route.path); }) 
  next(); 
});


app.use((req, res, next) => {
  //This code will run before the handler of the api, at the beginning of the request 
  //console #2
  console.log(req.route.path);
});


app.post('/chnagePass/:id', handeler...) //etc
```

So the console #1, happening at the end of the request, prints /chnagePass/:id.
console #2 doesn't work, req.route is undefined at this point.

But I would like to get this path name on console #2 (in my case, by the name of the route, I can decide what will be the timeout from some configuration).

How could I get the route name at this point (for example /chnagePass/:id)  ? Is it possible?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The `req.route` is populated only for middleware with a route. But since you are executing console#1 after the request, I believe the `req` object has already been mutated by then.

I was able to reproduce what you see with this code

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("1: " + JSON.stringify(req.route));
  }, 2000);
  next();
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("2: Route: " + JSON.stringify(req.route));
  console.log("2: Path: " + req.originalUrl);
  next();
});

app.get("/magic/:id", function(req, res) {
  console.log("3: " + JSON.stringify(req.route));
  res.send("Houdini " + req.params.id);
});

app.listen(3300, function() {
  console.log("Server UP!");
});
```

You can still get the exact path of the request by accessing `req.originalUrl` like in the code above but that gives you the exact path used and not the matcher defined.

Comment: Is there any known way to get the path without the params? to match string to string with the endpoint name?

Comment: or maybe you can suggest any way to add a handler for every route in the app before the real handlers without having to call it in every route?

Comment: Well, `app.use()` does run before every other route assuming its the first middleware that you register

Comment: But on app.use() req.route is still not populated, right? How can I assign a function for all the routes after the population? Instead of for example
app.get("/magic/:id", [add_timeout, function(req, res) {
  res.send(..);
}]); and app.get("/magic2/:id", [add_timeout, function(req, res) {
  res.send(..);
}]);

Comment: Yup. That will work but you would have to make sure to add that middleware to every route. From the [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.route), `req.route` "Contains the currently-matched route, a string.". Don't think there is way to get it any other way.